# Terminated app install corrupted SD card data

Tags: sd-card, lg

I was downloading an app for my LG-90 and it was taking forever. It had been minutes, so i restarted my phone. The phone would not restart; I'd see the T-Mobile logo and LG logo but it would not get as far as the home screen.

I started playing around with it and I found that if I took the SD card out it'd restart fine. I kept a lot of data on that card so I mounted it while the phone was powered on and was able to copy it's contents to my PC. The Lost.DIR seems to be full with all the data I had on the SD card; all photos, videos, etc. But none of them have a file extension so I can't tell what's what. I have to rename things to .png or .mp3 and see it they play or whatever.

I've unmounted and erased the SD card an remounted it, but the phone still seems to think the old data is on there. It says there's not enough space if I try move an app there. Also Photos has never worked right since (black screen when trying to view photos).

Anyone had an issue like this before?
Any suggestions on how to recover this data & get the SD card working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the bad news is the solution to this issue was;

1. Back up all phone data
2. Restore factory settings
3. Get a new sd card

I went with a 16GB SanDisk to replace the 32GB Samsung EVO sd card.
Good news is it only cost $11 and restoring contacts from Google servers is a great feature.